# Strange metallic shading/reflections

Tags: rendering, shaders

I think im having a weird reflection issue with a metallic surface. The small silver switches look great, but the big foot switches look odd. Im wondering if there is an issue or thats just how things are reflecting. I included 2 angles.

[image]
[image]

My normals are good, no double vertices. Am i missing a troubleshooting step? The shading is just the BSDF and i turned metallic to 1.0 and just adjusted roughness, very simple. No UVs either.

[image]

The green box looks good, reflecting nicely. The red box looks kinda flat or not shiny like the green box. And again, i think its just how the lighting is that makes it look "flat", but i was just seeing if maybe i was doing something wrong.

Comment: could you please share your object? (just the knob) https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hi, i uploaded it, hope it worked. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2pQSDodV" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2pQSDodV/)

Comment: everything seems all right, perhaps show a close-up screenshot to show specifically the problem you're talking about

Comment: Hi, ive updated the original post.

Comment: I honestly think its just the weird reflections in the viewport. Some other angles and in the final render, things make more sense. Thank you for your time.

Comment: So it turns out the unwanted results i was getting was due to those areas being over exposed and blown out. False color is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflections of the environment at infinity are *extremely* sensitive to the interpolation of normals across faces, which are calculated from the vertex, (or per-face vertex,) normals at the corners of triangulated faces at render-time.

So one thing you can do to adjust the regions of the environment which are reflected, and therefore the 'focus' of the reflections, is to introduce, and/or adjust bevels on loops surrounding relatively large faces, as on the right, below.

[image]

You had some changes of angle without bevels in your model; I put a couple of 2-segment bevels in there, and adjusted their profile with overlays switched off. so I could see what was up without wireframe in the way. I also replaced your other bevels, to adjust their widths and profiles.

My result. of course, may not be exactly the one you want, but if you go ahead and do the same with your copy, you'll see how dramatic the effects can be.

Comment: Thanks for this useful tip. I thought i beveled most of the obvious hard edges as it has always been said to never leave sharp edges. Did you do every edge?

Comment: I bevelled everywhere there was a sharp change of angle next to large faces, by hand, in this case, rather than using a Bevel modifier by angle, so I could tweak the profiles individually. It's just one way of setting the normals which get interpolated across the faces.. you could do it with Normal Edit modifiers, etc., but that all gets a bit more elaborate? Maybe someone with more experience manipulating normals directly can suggest a quick and snappy way.

Comment: I see. Well this definitely does help along with making sure the exposure is good too. Just did a back to back render and it completely changes some spots. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @RikkyRichardsonn Consider mark answer as accepted so other can see it from main list (it keeps site better organized). Thank you https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour